# Transferring information between 2 programs (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, network-programming

I just started learning a bit about **windows** socket programming. I thought I would write a simple multi-player **console** game(nothing very fancy) using these things I learnt but then WinSock can't be used in console programs(realized this quite later-so dumb of me!).

So is there any way that I run 2 programs-the WinSock program and the game and somehow *transfer the information* received using the Winsock program to my game?

Thanks!

P.S. I would like to avoid any external libraries, if possible

Comment: What makes you say that Winsock cannot be used in console applications?

Comment: Are You really needed to use sockets? Try pipes.

Comment: There's no particular reason you couldn't use sockets without windows.  In fact, most network services by definition use sockets, but don't (and by default, *can't*) have a window.

Comment: you can use WinSock in console , just include the library.

Comment: @cHao: Not having a window on the user's desktop is not the same as not having a window.  Message-only windows are fairly common.

Comment: So I wouldn't be needing WinMain as an entry point for my app, right?

Comment: @milindsrivastava1997: If it's a console app, no.  Just use `main` as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run WinSock in console application you should include those libraries

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
```

And link to

```
ws2_32.lib    MSVC
libws2_32.a   GCC
```

Comment: so to do this I should code the winsock stuff in the main function? (because it's a console app)

Comment: you can even code it in some custom class or whatever.
lets say you can create your own class that manages connections.
and your messages transferring.

Comment: so I don't need the WinMain function as an entry point for my application?

Comment: Use int main() as in console applications.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good tutorial on WinSock:

http://www.madwizard.org/programming/tutorials/netcpp/4

Some Microsoft Stuff:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737629(v=vs.85).aspx

Some more stuff and examples:

http://www.tenouk.com/Winsock/Winsock2example9.html